# RowSource property error vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to write a code that converts an input range into an array, then feeds that array into the RowSource for a listbox in my form.

According to MSDN the "RowSource" property for list/combo box should accept arrays, so I'm not sure why Im getting a runtime error here:

```
 Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim myarray As Variant


Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("List")
myarray = RangeToArray(Range("List"))
UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = "myarray"


End Sub
Function RangeToArray(inputRange As Range) As Variant
   Dim inputArray As Variant
   inputArray = inputRange.Value

   'operations on inputArray
   '...'

   RangeToArray = inputArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

try `UserForm1.ListBox1.List = myarray`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Excel VBA help:

> The RowSource property accepts worksheet ranges from Microsoft Excel.

If you have a MSDN link that says otherwise, please post it.

Anyway, to get the result you want, change

```
UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = "myarray"
```

to

```
UserForm1.ListBox1.List = myarray
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wil attempt this and get back to you. Please try this on vba :   Option Explicit

Sub test()

UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3")

End Sub
 you will see that you will get a type mismatch error

Comment: I know that will give an error, it's because it tries to assign the default property of the range, which is `Value`, an array.  `RowSource` needs to be set to a valid range address, which can be `A1` or the name of a named range.  Given that your post indicates you want to manipulate the data retrieved from a range before loading into the list, using the `List` property is the only way to go