# Can listbox.rowsource property accept a range?

Tags: vba, excel

According to this thread: [RowSource property error vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042431/rowsource-property-error-vba/32042618#32042618)

Listbox.rowsource can accept a range.

However when I run this

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A2")

End Sub
```

I get a type mismatch error. Could someone please shine some light on what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource takes a string:

Use this: `UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = ActiveSheet.Name & "!A1:A2"`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I changed my code from having the active sheet with a named range for the `RowSource` to a different sheet.  You can use the `RefersTo` property of a name as follows:

```
MyUserForm.Listbox1.Rowsource = ThisWorkbook.Names("rangename").RefersTo
```

If the named range is on the active sheet, then the following will also work:

```
MyUserForm.Listbox1.Rowsource = "rangename"
```

*But who likes changing the active sheet just to load a listbox?*